# Django Apache and name-based VirtualHost

Tags: django, apache, virtualhost

I have recently locally deployed Django project on Apache server Fedora 36. Everything work good when accessing site by ip. The issue that could not access it by hostname. I am getting "Bad Request (400)" error.

here my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName calljournal.local
        alias /static /var/www/django_project/call_journal/static
        <Directory /var/www/django_project/call_journal/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/django_project/call_journal>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess calljournal.local python-path=/var/www/django_project/virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup calljournal.local
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django_project/call_journal/call_journal/wsgi.py
        redirect / https://192.168.1.109
</VirtualHost>
```

and my hosts file

```
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.1.109 calljournal.local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enter the hostname in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` settings.

Comment: Of course I forgot it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome, please approve my answer to close this question. Thx.